# Before insert (statement level trigger) isn't working

Tags: database, postgresql, function, triggers

Below statements I have executed:

```
create table tab1(id int , name varchar(10) , city varchar(10) , latest bool default true);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.updateoldrow()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
update tab1 set latest ='0' where name = new.name and city = new.city and latest = '1';
RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
;

create trigger trig_updateoldrow before
insert
on
public.tab1 for each statement execute procedure updateoldrow();

insert into tab1 values(1,'Shiwangini','xyz','true');
insert into tab1 values(2,'Shiwangini','xyz','true');
```

I have created a table + function (to update old record to 'false' with the same matching value criteria) + then created a statement level trigger(before insert) -> then inserted 2 test records into that.
Now, when I run 'select * from tab1;' as per expectation first value with id=1 should be set to 'false'. However, it is not happening. I have also checked execution plan of insert statement, so  it is calling trigger:

```
    explain (analyze true, verbose, costs, buffers)insert into tab1 
    values(2,'Shiwangini','xyz','true');

    Insert on public.tab1  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=81) (actual time=0.113..0.113 rows=0 
    loops=1)
    Buffers: shared read=1 dirtied=1
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=81) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
    Output: 2, 'Shiwangini'::character varying(10), 'xyz'::character varying(10), true
    Planning Time: 0.020 ms
    Trigger trig_updateoldrow: time=0.060 calls=1
    Execution Time: 0.128 ms
```

However, if the same thing I'm trying to achieve with row level trigger- It is working properly and updating the old value.

Here, I'm unable to understand why statement level trigger isn't performing as expected. Any reason for this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) says

> NEW
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers.
> **This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.**

so the update can't work properly since the `NEW` value is null. You really need a row level trigger.